# Using javascript to access php variable

Tags: php, javascript

At http://nwgerh.site88.net/default.php, the code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$url = "http://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to use Javascript to access the JSON from PHP. See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUTbs/) (based on [this tutorial](http://www.darian-brown.com/pass-a-php-array-to-javascript-as-json-using-ajax-and-json_encode/)), but there are errors.

What's wrong? Is there a cross-domain issue?

Comment: I'm getting: Timestamp: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: ... have you tried adding a `)` after the argument list?

Comment: Ok, I fixed that, but I'm still not getting anything: http://jsfiddle.net/XUTbs/1/

Comment: now it's a cross domain issue: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://nwgerh.site88.net/default.php. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: ok, so any alternatives?

Comment: And you've checked that your PHP code works properly?

Comment: To be honest, I'm just a novice, so I'm not exactly sure how to check if `$data` works.

Comment: @ErahaagrWaegah - run the PHP code in your browser. Does it output what you expect it to output?

Comment: Ok, I ran the code and this is what it does: http://pastebin.com/MXT6fwyB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please post what error you're getting..

But your fiddle had an error anyway:

```
$.getJSON('http://nwgerh.site88.net/default.php', function(data) {
    document.write(data);
}​);​
```

It was missing the trailing `)`

it should work if it's on the same domain

Comment: It's not on the same domain, is that a problem?

Comment: you'll have to use jsonp then, or set the origin headers `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`, as the other post said

Comment: Ok, I added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to the PHP file, and still nothing's happening.

Comment: I just tested it in jsFiddle using my example above... I get the response.

Comment: Sorry, I'm all over the place today. Can you link to your jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ?callback={} to the URL. This will force a JSONP AJAX request in jQuery -- which would eliminate your cross-domain issue.

Comment: Change {} to ? (question mark). Sorry. But, it is in fact a cross-domain issue and this solution should solve the problem.

Comment: Since your response is returning an HTML document, it won't appear using document.write (you can see it by viewing the source, but it won't show on screen). You'll need to parse the response data.